# Docker Communications link failure with JDBC

Tags: docker

I was looking for the answer of this problem, but couldn't find any solution.
I am trying to push my application on docker, but when I put "docker-compose" it says:

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:latest

ADD target/my-app.jar /my-app.jar

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java", "-jar", "/my-app.jar"]
```

and these are my .properties:

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/rabbit_messages?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234


spring.rabbitmq.host = rabbitmq
spring.rabbitmq.port = 5672
spring.rabbitmq.username = guest
spring.rabbitmq.password = guest

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

if i run it locally with changing the containers names with "localhost" it works fine.
when i run it on docker i get the errors which i've posted above.
Anyone could help, please?

docker-compose:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  my-app:
    container_name: myapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - rabbitmq
      - mysql
    environment:
        -SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3307/rabbit_messages?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=1234
      - SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - mysql

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3307"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=rabbit_messages
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=1234
    restart: on-failure
```

Comment: If your issue is occurring when running docker-compose, please provide your `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: @im_baby I added it. Sorry for not quoting it, but I am via mobile.

Comment: In your properties you have mysql:3306 and in your docker-compose you have mysql:3307. Could that be?

Comment: Yes, @UrbanoJVR looks to be correct. In addition `links` is deprecated so be sure to stop using it. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#links

Comment: Already tried without the links - same thing happens

Comment: I think you need port 3306, as this is the default mysql port. Be sure to change it also in SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL

Comment: It doesnt works again. I seen something called static network and should be settled. I will read about it tomorrow.